# jQuery set dynamic ID via PHP

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I'm having trouble finding how to do this.

I just want to take a $name passed in the url (`photos.php?name=project1`) and set it as a div's ID in jQuery (`<div id="project1">`).

To be more specific, I'm trying to pass it here:

```
cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="UNIQUEPHPID" />' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes like this:

```
$('selector').attr('id', '<?php echo $_GET["name"];?>');
```

Replace `selector` with the element id/class you want to apply the id from url to.

Or if you want to use it as selector:

```
$('div#<?php echo $_GET["name"];?>');
```

**Note:** The id you use should be as per the specification, check out the @David Dorward comments below.

Comment: The only characters that `htmlspecialchars` will convert to entities … are those which aren't allowed in an id attribute value anyway. Also, since this is JavaScript, a `'` character will break the string, and `htmlspecialchars` doesn't touch it by default.

Comment: @David: Not sure what you mean, how do you get the security, url can be tampered with?

Comment: Since it is JavaScript, you need to escape it for JavaScript. Then, *if* the JS is being embedded in HTML you need to escape characters with special meaning in HTML. You shouldn't deal with HTML escapes first and ignore the JS.

Comment: That said, the first thing you should do is make sure that it conforms to the specification for id attributes — a letter ([A-Za-z]) optionally followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). None of those characters have special meaning inside a JavaScript string or in HTML anyway, which makes either kind of escaping redundant. Since ID attributes have to be unique in a document you also need to check for that uniqueness.

Comment: @David: Yap id should be as per specification, i will update the answer to reflect your comments.

Comment: This doesn't work. It simply makes the Id "<?php echo $_GET["name"];?>"

Comment: `cache[ url ] = $( '<div class="section"/>' )`, and in the callback: `$('.section').attr('id', '<?php echo $_GET["name"];?>');`

Comment: You must **check** that the id conforms to the spec (described in my previous comment) — otherwise you open yourself up with a huge XSS hole. Never echo out the content of `$_GET` blindly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, that's a bit over my head. The ID's will always be lowercase letters only, no numbers or anything, but I think it needs to be passed in the `cache[ url ]` line in order for the browser to cache it properly.

Comment: @steve — the id is specified in the URL. They can be whatever the attacker giving the link to the visitor wants.